# How can I include a function (and its parameter) within an event handler, without the function being called on page load?

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring this code

```
$("#one").on("click", function() {
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("1");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("1");
        }
    });
    $("#two").on("click", function() {
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("2");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("2");
        }
    });
    $("#three").on("click", function() {
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("3");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("3");
        }
    });
    $("#four").on("click", function() {
        console.log("4");
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("4");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("4");
        }
    });
    $("#five").on("click", function() {
        console.log("5");
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("5");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("5");
        }
    });
    $("#six").on("click", function() {
        console.log("6");
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("6");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("6");
        }
    });
    $("#seven").on("click", function() {
        console.log("7");
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("7");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("7");
        }
    });
    $("#eight").on("click", function() {
        console.log("8");
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("8");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("8");
        }
    });
    $("#nine").on("click", function() {
        console.log("9");
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("9");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("9");
        }
    });
    $("#zero").on("click", function() {
        console.log("0");
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push("0");
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push("0");
        }
    });
```

into this

```
function pushNumber(numberToPush) {
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push(numberToPush);
        }
        else {
            secondArray.push(numberToPush);
        }
    }

    $("#one").on("click", pushNumber("1"));
    $("#two").on("click", pushNumber("2"));
    $("#three").on("click", pushNumber("3"));
    $("#four").on("click", pushNumber("4"));
    $("#five").on("click", pushNumber("5"));
    $("#six").on("click", pushNumber("6"));
    $("#seven").on("click", pushNumber("7"));
    $("#eight").on("click", pushNumber("8"));
    $("#nine").on("click", pushNumber("9"));
    $("#zero").on("click", pushNumber("0"));
```

When I try the above code, the pushNumber function is being called on page load.  I understand that this is happening because I have put parentheses, thereby calling the function.  But I do not know how I can pass a parameter to the function without doing it this way.

I'd appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is "curry" a function, or generate a new function that already has some arguments added into it.

First, we'll make a function to generate a new function for each click handler:

```
function generateHandler(argument) {
    return function() {
        pushNumber(argument);
    };
}
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
$("#one").on("click", generateHandler("1"));
```

Comment: Thank you for that Samuel.  Seems a very useful concept, although it would probably be my new favourite one due to the name anyway ;).

Comment: Note one further refactoring you can now do on top of this:  `["zero", "one", ... "nine"].forEach(function(name, nbr) {$("#" + name).on("click").generateHandler("" + nbr);})`

Comment: It might make more sense to add a data-* attribute to the elements, and then do something like:

`$("some selector").click(function() { pushNumber($(this).attr("data-value")); });`

Answer (score 1):

What you want is something called *partial application* or *currying*.  You can do it manually for your case with a higher-order function, like this:

```
function pushNumber(numberToPush) 
    return function() {
        if(operator === undefined) {
            firstArray.push(numberToPush);
        } else {
            secondArray.push(numberToPush);
        }
    };
}
```

But many utiility libraries also offer a `curry` or `partial` function that you might be able to use to wrap your function.